# Running a testng suite in an already running java vm

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, testng

I would like to run tests for my java classes executing within a third-party application that spawns its own java vm.
Since my java classes cannot execute outside of that java vm (they use services provided by it), also my tests need to run within that java vm.

One option I have is to run the TestNG suite from within the third-party application (which provides a java command line):

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml
```

Another option, which is the one I'd like to evaluate for now, would be to run the tests from within Eclipse.

Which approach do you suggest I follow for this second option? Shall I load the third-party app within Eclipse, but then? I guess I'm stuck.